# Bot Framework Location Picker Not Found

Tags: node.js, emulation, botframework

Using Node, I installed botbuilder-location package and the following code :

```
var locationDialog = require('botbuilder-location');
var options = {
    prompt: "Where are you ?",
    useNativeControl: true,
    reverseGeocode: true
  };
locationDialog.getLocation(session, options);
```

I got the error :

> Error: Dialog[botbuilder-location:locationPickerPrompt] not found.

In the bot builder emulator. Is location dialog supported in the emulator ?

Comment: What version of the botbuilder-location are you using? And when are you getting the error? Right after the getLocation and when you are trying to access the result?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was just missing this line :

```
bot.library(locationDialog.createLibrary('API_KEY');
```